# Android webView Application - Can't get back button to go back a page

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

I am a little new to Android coding, so I'm having some problems making my Android Application.

My problem is, that I when I open my app and it loads my webpage, then when I wanna go a step backwards it just closes the app. I am trying to enable the back button, to go back a page, but I can't seem to get it "binded" with my actual "webView"

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
package com.kevi2129.ris.elevintra;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint({ "CutPasteId", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        ourBrow.loadUrl("http://www.ringkobingskole.dk/mobil/");
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && ourBrow1.canGoBack()) {
            ourBrow1.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Here's my ActivityMain.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.
-Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Override the onBackPressed and handle your custom `WebView` behavior:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView != null && mWebView.canGoBack()){
            mWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare WebView as a class member

```
 WebView myWebView; 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
        ... // rest of the code
```

and use `myWebView`

```
  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
```

Also you have

```
   WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); // remove this statement
   WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Remove one of them and use either `ourBrow` or `myWebView`.

Suppose you remove `WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);` first initialize  `myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView)` and then

```
  mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.ringkobingskole.dk/mobil/");
```

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

As of 2.0 we have a new little API to make this more simple and easier to discover and get right:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (myWebView!=null && myWebView.canGoBack())
 {
   myWebView.goBack();      
 }
else
 {
   finish();    
 }
}
```

Comment: @user2999321 you had webview initialized twice. declare it as a class member or it becomes local to `onCreate`. Use one either  `ourBrow` or `myWebView`.